# #VALX value in MS Chart in C# isn't coming in "M/d H:mm" format

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip, mschart

I wrote the following Winforms code:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "M/d H:mm ";
```

This makes my X-axis seen as, for example 11/25 8:00. But when I provide the tooltip for the datapoints it just provides the date and not the format "M/d H:mm".
 Here is my code:

```
chart1.Series[0].ToolTip = "Computer Name: #SERIESNAME \nDate & Time: #VALX  \nLevel: #VALY";`
```

And the tooltip result which I got was this:

Computer Name: *COMP NAME*
Date & Time: *11/25/2013*
Level: *4*

I want the "Date & Time" value as " 11/25 8:00", which is being showed in the X-axis but not in the #VALX tooltip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this: `#VALX{M/d H:mm}`.
So your code will be:

```
chart1.Series[0].ToolTip = "Computer Name: #SERIESNAME \nDate & Time: #VALX{M/d H:mm}  \nLevel: #VALY";
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try `LabelToolTip` property instead of `Tooltip`, when dealing with data points, at least that's what [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.datapointcustomproperties.labeltooltip%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) hints

Comment: `LabelToolTip` doesn't solve the problem. but thanks for trying.